# Reflection of the chain-condition: clarifying a suspected typo

Tags: gn.general-topology

In  the 2002 paper *[Reflecting Lindelöfness](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641%2801%2900135-3)* in Topology and its Applications, J. Baumgartner and F. Tall state that "by an easy  Löwenheim–Skolem argument," an uncountable (say $T_2$ or $T_3$) ccc topological space has a ccc subspace of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

My question is: Is this (reflection statement) actually true?

(Of course, I can see for example that indeed, "by an easy (ramification) argument," this is true for the linearly orderable topological spaces).

Comment: Can you write a title related to the mathematical contents? you have the whole post to describe what you're looking for.

Comment: I upgraded the link to use a doi and also gave more details about the paper.

Comment: @DavidRoberts  Special thanks for help!

Comment: Do you really think that a title finishing with a comma will have a long life? :) anyway, the new first part of the title (the second one should be cut and pasted to the post) doesn't give a lot of information. Think of a list of questions browsed by people.

Comment: @WillBrian  I suspect that you have a (not so uncommon) confusion between a Boolean Algebra and its topological Stone space.

Comment: @WillBrian could you explain why $X \cap M$ has the ccc?

Comment: @NotMike I'm sorry but I just don't see it. How exactly is it used the fact that M is closed under countable sequences? How does any failure of the ccc for $X \cap M$ *automatically* produces a failure of the ccc for $X$? I'm sure there is something basic that I'm forgetting, but I just don't see it.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega: Sorry I never got back to you about your previous comment. (When I read it I was busy with something else, and I meant to come back to the problem and then forgot all about it instead.) Anyway, it looks like your concerns were justified, and the "easy" argument I had in mind doesn't work, as I can now see from your answer (+1). I may take some time to see whether $X \cap M$ has any nice properties when we assume more about $X$, but it may be that the ccc doesn't reflect in this way, even for really nice $X$.

Comment: @WillBrian, don´t worry, I´ve been there. I added to my answer some positive results using elementary submodels.

Comment: If it helps readers (people like me who have to spend 1min on the web to find a definition): ccc means that there are no uncountably many pairwise disjoint open subsets.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega it seems I was implicitly assuming the space was Tychonoff and sitting comfortably inside some product of unit intervals. Excellent answer.

Comment: @NotMike even for a Tychonoff $X$ I don't see why $X \cap M$ is automatically ccc, even for a countably closed M.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega you don't need countable closure if only want $X\cap M$ to be ccc. Since without loss of generality you can assume $X\subset [0,1]^S$, in which case the map $\pi(x) = x\cap M$ will be continuous and irreducible (since the base of the product is in $M$). It'll be irreducible by elementary.

Comment: @NotMike I still don't follow. The map you describe is irreducible (just because it is injective) but it might not be closed. If your claim is that the reflection holds for all Tychonoff spaces you should write an answer and include some details.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega see my answer. I think we've been been talking about two different things.

Answer (score 8):

The reflection statement is dramatically false at least for Hausdorff spaces.

**Theorem 1.** For any infinite cardinal $\kappa$ there is a Hausdorff ccc space $X$ with no uncountable ccc subspace of cardinality less than or equal than $\kappa$.

**Proof.** Let $X=2^\kappa$ with the topology $\tau$ generated by sets of the form $P \cap C$ where $P$ is basic clopen on the product topology and $C\subseteq X$ with $|X \setminus C|<2^\kappa$. Note that the generating set is closed under finite intersections so it is in fact a base for $\tau$.

Clearly $\tau$ contains the product topology on $X$ so $(X,\tau)$ is a Hausdorff space. Moreover since any clopen in the product topology has size $2^\kappa$ we have that for any two basic open sets $P_1 \cap C_1$ and $P_2 \cap C_2$, $$(P_1 \cap C_1) \cap (P_2 \cap C_2) \neq \emptyset \iff P_1 \cap P_2 \neq \emptyset.$$
It follows that $(X,\tau)$ is ccc (since the product topology is ccc).

Finally if $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ with $|Y|<2^\kappa$ (in particular if $|Y|\leq \kappa$) then $Y$ is discrete. To see this just note that given $y \in Y$ we can take $C=(X \setminus Y) \cup \{y\}$ and since $|X \setminus C|=|Y \setminus \{y\}|<2^\kappa$, we have that $\{y\}=Y \cap (X \cap C)$ is open in $Y$. Hence $Y$ is not ccc unless $Y$ is countable. $\square$

However there are some positive results.

**Theorem 2.** If $(X,\tau)$ is an uncountable ccc topological space and $\chi(X) \leq \aleph_1$ then $X$ contains a ccc subspace of size $\aleph_1$.

**Proof.** Fix $M$ an elementary submodel of $H_\theta$ (with $\theta$ large enough) such that $\omega_1 \subseteq M$, $(X,\tau) \in M$ and $|M|=\aleph_1$. By elementarity the space $(X \cap M, \tau \cap M)$ is ccc and $|X \cap M|=\aleph_1$ (because $\omega_1 \subset M$). But since $\chi(X) \leq \aleph_1$, again by elementarity and the fact that $\omega_1 \subset M$, we have that $\tau \cap M$ generates the subspace topology in $X \cap M$. $\square$

**Theorem 3.** If $(X,\tau)$ is an uncountable ccc compact Hausdorff topological space then $X$ contains a ccc subspace of size $\aleph_1$.

**Proof.** Fix $M$ an elementary submodel of $H_\theta$ (with $\theta$ large enough) such that $\omega_1 \subseteq M$, $(X,\tau) \in M$ and $|M|=\aleph_1$. Define a relation on $X$ by $x\sim y$ if and only if $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $f \in C(X)\cap M$. It is fairly well known that this is an equivalence relation for which the quotient space $X/M$ is Hausdorff (in fact $X/M$ is Tychonoff whenever $X$ is Tychonoff, even if $X$ is not compact), the quotient map $\rho:X \to X/M$ is inyective when restricted to $X \cap M$ (so $|X/M| \geq \aleph_1$) and $\rho(X \cap M)$ is dense in $X/M$ (so $d(X/M) \leq \aleph_1$).

Fix a closed $Z \subseteq X$ such that the restriction $\rho:Z \to X/M$ is suryective and irreducible. Since $X/M$ is ccc being a continuous image of the ccc space $X$, we get by irreducibility that $Z$ is also ccc. Since $d(X/M) \leq \aleph_1$ we can find $Y \subseteq X$ with $|Y|=\aleph_1$ such that $\rho(Y)$ is dense in $X/M$. By irreducibility $Y$ is dense in $Z$ and therefore $Y$ is the ccc space we were looking for. $\square$

A combination of the ideas in the proofs of Theorems 2 and 3 can be used to prove that the reflection statement is true for $T_3$ spaces of pointwise countable type ($h(X) \leq \aleph_1$ is enough). In particular it is true for locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

I don´t know what happens for $T_3$ spaces in general (note that the space described in the proof of Theorem 1 is not regular).

Comment: This is an excellent and lucidly presented solution to my reflection question. I especially liked - in the positive result - the use of the ring  C(X)  for general compact spaces in place of the usual clopen algebra for a Boolean space. On the other hand, I think it is still conceivable that, for $\kappa \geq (2^{\omega_1})^+$, there may exist a dense subspace of $2^\kappa$ with no subset of size $\aleph_1$ reflecting ccc.

Comment: @IsaacGorelic , I wrote a paper (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.09103) about this. It includes a generalization of the positive result that I presented here, and also I constructed for each uncountable regular $\kappa$ a ccc subspace of $2^\kappa$ of size $\kappa$ with no uncountable ccc subspace of cardinality less than $\kappa$.

Comment: Right, your paper there (see arxiv.org/abs/1804.09103) is VERY good. And your quotation of my question here as Question 1 there is VERY precise!

Answer (score 0):

This is meant to flesh out a claim made in a previous comment and clear up a point of confusion about what the topology on $X \cap M$ is normally assumed to be when trying to reflect properties of $X$ using elementary submodels.

**Proposition:**  Assume $(X,\tau)$ is Tychonoff. If $M\prec H(\theta)$ is an elementary sub-model with $X,\tau \in M$. Then, $(X_M, \tau_M)$ where $X_M = X \cap M$ and $\tau_M$ is the topology generated by $\{ U \cap X_M: U \in \tau \cap M \}$, is homeomorphic to a dense subset of a continuous image of $X$.

In particular, if $(X,\tau)$ is c.c.c., then so is $(X_M, \tau_M)$

**Proof:** Without loss of generality assume $X \subset [0,1]^{\lambda}$ ($\lambda$ a cardinal) with the topology on $X$ taken to be the topology induced by $[0,1]^{\lambda}$.

Let $\mathcal{B} = \cup \{ \{ [0, q), (q,p), (p,1] \}: q < p \text{ and } p,q\in (0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $\mathbb{P} = \mathsf{Fn}(\lambda, \mathcal{B})$ (the set of finite partial functions $p\subset \lambda\times \mathcal{B}$); moreover for each $p \in \mathbb{P}$ define $$[p] = \{ a \in [0,1]^{\lambda}: (\forall \gamma \in dom(p))(a(\gamma) \in p(\gamma))\}.$$  Noting that $\{ [p]:p \in \mathbb{P} \}$ is a base for the product topology on $[0,1]^{\lambda}$, we readily have that $\mathcal{B}_X=\{ [p] \cap X: p \in \mathbb{P} \}$ is a base for the relative topology on $X$.

**Claim:** For any elementary submodel $M\prec H(\theta)$:

- $\mathcal{B} \in M$, $\mathcal{B} \subset M$, and $M \cap \mathbb{P} = \mathsf{Fn}(\lambda \cap M, \mathcal{B})$.
- Assuming $X \in M$: the set $Y_0 = \{ x_0 \cap M: x_0 \in X \cap M \} \subset [0,1]^{\lambda \cap M}$ is a dense subset of the space $Y=\pi_M[X]$ (the image of $X$ under the projection $\pi_M:[0,1]^{\lambda} \rightarrow [0,1]^{\lambda \cap M}$.)

*Proof of Claim:* For the first portion, simply note that $\mathcal{B}$ is a definable and countable family of subsets of $[0,1]$; in addition to see that $p \in \mathbb{P} \cap M \iff p \in \mathsf{Fn}(\lambda \cap M, \mathcal{B})$. First note that the set $dom(p)$ is definable from $p$ by a $\Delta_0$ formula. As such, it follows that $p \in M $ implies $dom(p) \in M$ which, since $p$ is finite, also entails $dom(p) \subset M$. For the second portion, it is enough to observe that by elementarity, for every $p \in \mathbb{P} \cap M$, if $[p] \cap X \neq\emptyset$ then, there is some $x \in [p] \cap X \cap M$ serving as a witness. This is enough to establish the second portion (and the proposition) since for each relevant $p$, we have $dom(p) \subset M \cap \lambda$ and the projection $\pi_M$ does not effect indices laying within $M$.

### Edit:

**Theorem:** Assume $(X,\tau)$ is Tychonoff and c.c.c. and $M \prec H(\theta)$ with $X \in M$, then  $X_M = X \cap M$ (as a subspace of $X$) is c.c.c.

**Proof:** As before assume $X \subset [0,1]^\lambda$ and $M\prec H(\theta)$ are such that $X\in M$. Next, suppose $X$ has the c.c.c., then

- $Y = cl(X)\in M$ is compact and c.c.c.,
- The compact space $Z = cl(Y_M)$ contains $X_M$, and
- The restriction of the projection $\pi_M(x)=x\vert_M$ to $Z$ is irreducible and maps $Z$ onto $\pi_M[ Y ]\subset [0,1]^{\lambda \cap M}$ (this follows from the proof of the previous claim, combined with the observation that for any proper closed  $Z_0\subset Z$, we have $\emptyset \neq Y_M \cap (Z\backslash Z_0) \subset M$)

With that setup, for *any* $p \in \mathbb{P}$, define $U_p = \pi_M[Z] \backslash \pi_M[Z \backslash [p]] \subset [0,1]^{\lambda \cap M}$. Then each $U_p \subset \pi_M[Z] \subset [0,1]^{\lambda \cap M}$ is (relatively) open. Moreover, for any $p, q \in \mathbb{P}$, $$X_M \cap [p] \cap [q] = \emptyset \implies U_p \cap U_q \cap \pi_M[X_M] = \emptyset. $$

It follows that if $X_M$ is not a c.c.c. subspace of $X$, then $\pi_M[X_M]$ is not a c.c.c. subspace of $\pi_M[Z]$; however, noting that $\pi_M[X_M]$ is a dense subset of $\pi_M[X]$, which is in turn a dense subset of $\pi_M[Z] = \pi_M[Y]$, we have that $\pi_M[Y]$ is not c.c.c. (a contradiction.)

**Remark:** I guess I should have been more clear in the Proposition, the space $(X_M, \tau_M)$ is homeomorphic to $\pi_M[X_M] \subset \pi_M[X]$, which is a dense subset of $\pi_M[X]$. Moreover, since the original Proposition applies to all Tychonoff spaces, it applies to any compact space within which $X$ embeds as a dense subset.

Comment: Note that if $(X,\tau)$ is any ccc space (no separation axioms needed) then $(X_M,\tau_M)$ is ccc just because $(U \cap M) \cap (V \cap M) = \emptyset$ implies $U \cap V = \emptyset$ whenever $U,V \in \tau \cap M$. But this topology on $X \cap M$ is usually weaker than the subspace topology, so this doesn't imply the reflection statement in the OP.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega filled in the details.

Comment: Sorry for being dense but $X \cap M$ might not be dense in $Y \cap M$ as you claim it is. For a concrete example take $Y=\beta\omega \setminus \omega$ and let $X=Y \setminus \{p\}$ for some weak P-point $p \in Y$. Then $Y \cap M=X \cap M \cup \{p\}$ and if $M$ is countable, $p$ is not in the closure of $X \cap M$.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega Oh, heh; I meant for both to be taken with their topology restricted to $M$. At any rate $\pi_M[X]$ (and $\pi_M[X_M]$) remains a dense subset of $\pi_M[Y]$. Which is all that matters.

Comment: But then $\pi_M[cl(X_M)]=\pi_M[Y]$ and hence the restriction of $\pi_M$ to $Z$ wasn't irreducible after all.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega the closure of $Y_M$ in $Y$, *is* irreducible. So I'll just change that bit. Good catch. (Cleaned up and combined two comments)